# Raise an event when last property is assigned

Tags: c#

Is there a way to run an event when the last property is assigned to an object? I don´t want to use INotifyPropertyChanged to fire the event every time a property value changed.
I want the event or method to fire **only** when the last property has been assigned.

For example here the event gets fired when the Color is assigned

```
            Model model = new Model();
            model.Blocks = 2;
            model.Layers = 3;

            ModelManager manager = new ModelManager();
            manager.Models.Add(model);

            model.Color = Color.Blue;
```

Here the event gets fired when the layers are assigned

```
            Model model = new Model();
            model.Blocks = 2;
            

            ModelManager manager = new ModelManager();
            manager.Models.Add(model);

            model.Color = Color.Blue;
            model.Layers = 3;
```

**EDIT:**
I dont have a certain amout of properties to be set to consider the object "complete". The problem is that I need to do some calculations with the properties that have been set but I dont want to repeat the calculations every time a property is changed. The time the object is created there is no problem to repeat the calculations. But then in execution time the applicationis going to change a lot of properties "at once" like hundred of times so I want to do this calculations as less as possible.

Comment: you need some logic within every property that checks if all others are already set to something. There's nothing built in to achieve that.

Comment: But what if I have 5 properties and only 3 have been assigned? That would work only if all the properties are assigned

Comment: How do you know when the "last" property is assigned?

Comment: What happens when the "last" property is assigned that can't happen when the "first" is assigned? Could you not just use a constructor where each property has an optional parameter?

Comment: So, say there's some code that sets 3 properties and then *conditionally* sets the other 2, for your 5 property object. Unless you have an ability to see into the future there's no way for your code to know that the third property being set is or will be the "last" property assigned.

Comment: You could start a timer whenever a property is changed. You decide how long the timer tick should be, for instance 100 ms. When the timer event triggers the last property has been set. This solution is not perfect, but what is on this Earth..

Comment: @Tormund: Regarding the edit... So are you saying that the object itself has no way of knowing what properties the consuming code is going to set?  If that's the case then the object has no way of knowing when the consuming code is "done".  It would be up to the consuming code to invoke a method on the object to perform the re-calculation when it's "done" setting properties.

Answer (score 1):

> I don´t want to use INotifyPropertyChanged to fire the event every time a property value changed.

Sure you do, just add some logic to only *conditionally* fire the event.  For example:

```
public string SomeProperty
{
    get { return this.someProperty; }
    set
    {
        if (value != this.someProperty)
        {
            this.someProperty = value;
            // only fire the event if the condition is met
            if (AllPropertiesAreSet())
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}

private bool AllPropertiesAreSet()
{
    return (
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SomeProperty) &&
        SomeOtherProperty != 0 &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(AThirdProperty)
    );
}
```

Basically each property would check if all of the properties "have been set" using whatever logic you want to use to define that state.  The first one to get a `true` response from the condition would be the "last" property to be set.

Alternatively it doesn't *need* to specifically be an `INotifyPropertyChanged` event.  You can create your own event, or just invoke a method, or do whatever you like in the body of that `if` block.

Comment: This will only work if al the properties have been set and I dont want that

Comment: @Tormund: Then what *do* you want?  What is the difference between “all of the other properties have been set” and “this is the last property to be set”?  Please clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you want to call method `PropertiesSet()` when all *required* properties have been set. You have to check in the property's `set()` method if this is the last property and, if so, initiate the calculations. To make it simple, I suggest to use nullable types and check for null to determine if the last property is set.

The example code below uses three *required* properties `Blocks`, `Colour` and `Title` and one *not required* property `Layers`.

```
public class Model
{
    private int? blocks = null;
    private Color? colour = null;
    private string title = null;

    public int? Blocks
    {
        get { return blocks; }
        set { blocks = value; PropertiesSet(); }
    }

    public Color? Colour
    {
        get { return colour; }
        set { colour = value; PropertiesSet(); }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; PropertiesSet(); }
    }

    public int Layers   // not required property
    { get; set; }

    private void PropertiesSet()
    {
        if (blocks is null || colour is null || title is null) return;

        // Add the calculations here
    }
}
```

The condition to abort `PropertiesSet()` may be more complex than just check for `null`. E.g. you may want to check for 0 `Blocks` and/or empty string `Title`, but you can reject such illegal values already when the properties are assigned.

You may remove the condition check from `PropertiesSet()` and place it in a separate method, e.g.:

```
private bool AllSet() => blocks is not null && colour is not null && title is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just setup a list of properties that have to be changed before anything happens (like firing an event) and implement some check in the setter of your properties.

```
public class Model
{
    private bool _alreadyDidSomething;
    private readonly IList<string> _requiredProperties = new List<string>
    {
        nameof(PropertyA),
        nameof(PropertyB)
    };

    private string _propertyA;
    public string PropertyA
    {
        get => _propertyA;
        set
        {
            if (_propertyA == value)
                return;
            _propertyA = value;
            
            RemoveProperty();
            DoSomething();
        }
    }

    private string _propertyB;
    public string PropertyB
    {
        get => _propertyB;
        set
        {
            if (_propertyB == value)
                return;
            _propertyB = value;

            RemoveProperty();
            DoSomething();
        }
    }

    private void RemoveProperty([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        _requiredProperties.Remove(propertyName);
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        if (_requiredProperties.Count == 0 && !_alreadyDidSomething)
        {
            // fire event or do whatever you want to do!
            _alreadyDidSomething = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Everytime you change a property for the first time, its name will get removed from the list. In the "DoSomething" method you can check this list and whether it is empty and then do whatever you want to do.

The advantage of this approach is, that you can even configure which properties are relevant for the whole object to be considered "complete" before doing something. And you can choose whether to exeucte your action multiple times from than on or not

```
var model1 = new Model();
model1.PropertyA = "Value A"; // Does not trigger the event.
model1.PropertyB = "Value B"; // Does trigger the event.

var model2 = new Model();
model2.PropertyB = "Value B"; // Does not trigger the event.
model2.PropertyA = "Value A"; // Does trigger the event.
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternative would be to just simply have a method in the class `Model` called `NotifyAll()` that implements `NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)` for all the properties in that class. Call that method only when you assign the last property some value.

Comment: That does not answer my question which is how can I know when the last property has been set

Comment: Your problem is still very unclear to me.